# Difference Boolean Not Working as Intended

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects

I'm fairly new to Blender so I'm sure this is a dumb question-

I am trying to create a house layout with holes for my doors. If you see the image below, I have the walls, with cubes for the door holes as separate objects.
[image: Layout]

However, if I apply a Boolean modifier to the walls with the Difference operation and the object being the Door holes, I get the below results:
[image: boolean modifier]

The below happens with the opposite (Boolean applied to the doorholes with Walls as the object):
[image: vice versa]

As you can see, the door frames are exposed but there's still a chunk of wall in between the door. This is the ideal result I'm looking for (it works for this door only). Note the window I have in the door.

[image: ideal result]

This is what the other doors get with the boolean. The front sides are exposed but there's still wall inside the doors.

[image: sad day]
[image: door rotated]

I appreciate whatever help I can get here. I have verified the following:

- There is no duplicate geometry
- Normals are all facing the proper direction

Answer (score 3):

FIXED IT:

I was using an old version of blender (2.83).

Updating to 9.23 and then selecting "Hole Tolerant" within the Boolean solver options fixed my issue.